# How to add upload feature and show upload file in rails using AWS S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services

I haven trying to create cloud based hosting platform for which i have already created all login management and user stuff. Recently i used paperclip for uploading profile picture in AWS S3 and it was successful. But i thought of adding upload feature in user page so after when user upload the file it should be saved in AWS S3. After successful upload user should be able to see his upload file and delete the file to. Is there some kind of gem or tutorial i can follow to do that?

Comment: I used carrierwave to upload from a rails app to s3: 
[Carrierwave on github](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)
Worked great for me. You can even set up background jobs for the upload using a gem called carrierwave-backgrounder

Comment: But it's only showing way to upload avatar. I want to upload files like doc, pdf and mp3 etc. Can you show me some example of uploading it?

Comment: [This rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

Answer (score 2):

You can use paper_clip gem which supports S3 upload and download. Check this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

Comment: I have already implemented Paperclip but i am not able to upload other file in home page. Can help me with that?

Comment: @AruzParajuli: can you eloborate what do you mean by other file? Could you possibly share what error are you getting?

Comment: Other file means pdf, Doc and etc. I have already managed to upload image in profile picture and create login page out of it. But after that i am not able to add upload feature in home page.

Comment: OK here it is https://github.com/aruzmeister/Upload. Just after login i am not able to implement the upload feature. Can you just fix that?

Comment: I think you have mentioned :styles in has_attached_file which is mostly used for images and may be culprit. Also you have content type validation which might allow images only.

Comment: So can define some changes that i can implement.

Comment: Can you comment your validations for a while in user model for content type and try to upload any PDF file.